# Dynamics 365 Portal Form Show Hide Field based on Check Box Value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365

I'm having an issue getting Java Script to work for a Dynamics 365 portal form.

The code is supposed to show hide an address field on the form when the option for physical subscriber is selected. This is a yes no Boolean.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Bind the onDisplaySectionChange function to the change event of the element with ID "ds_VoiceSubscriber".
    $("#ds_VoiceSubscriber").change(onDisplaySectionChange);
 
    // Calling onDisplaySectionChange immediately when the page loads.
    onDisplaySectionChange();
});
 
// Function to show or hide fields and tabs based on the selected value.
function onDisplaySectionChange() {
    var selectedValue = GetRadioSelectedValue($('#ds_VoiceSubscriber'));
 
    if (selectedValue === "1") {
        // Show the parent of the element with ID "Address1_Line1".
        $("#Address1_Line1").parent().show();
    } else {
        // Hide the parent of the element with ID "Address1_Line1".
        $("#Address1_Line1").parent().hide();
    }
}
 
// Function to get the selected value of a radio button group.
GetRadioSelectedValue = function (input) {
    if (!!$(input).find("input[type=radio]")) {
        var controlName = $(input).find("input[type=radio]").first().attr("name");
        if (!!controlName) {
            return $("input[name='" + controlName + "']:checked").val();
        }
    }
    return "";
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup as well?

Answer (score -2):

In your "GetRadioSelectedValue" function your input is the html-input-element and then you search inside that element for an html-input-element with type="radio" and can't find it. Search in that element's parent instead.

```
if (!!$(input).parent().find("input[type=radio]")) {
    var controlName = $(input).parent().find("input[type=radio]").first().attr("name");
```